# Sup norm bound for heat-like equation on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, markov-chains, heat-equation

I am interested in "heat-like" equations on $\mathbb{Z}$ defined by a transition kernel $K:\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{R}_+$, satisfying the following conditions for every $x\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$
\sum_y K(x,y) = 1, \qquad \sum_y y K(x,y) = x, \qquad \sum_y (y-x)^2 K(x,y) = 1.
$$
In addition, I am assuming a support condition so that $K(x,y) = 0$ when $|x-y| > 10$.

The kernel $K$ defines an evolution operator (which I'll call $T_K$) on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ via
$$
(T_Kf)(y) = \sum_x K(x,y) f(x).
$$

An example of such a kernel is given by $K(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}$ if $y=x\pm 1$ and $K(x,y)= 0$ otherwise.

I am curious about the properties of the operator $T_K^n$.

**Question:** Does the bound

$$
\|T_K^n f\|_{\ell^\infty} \leq C n^{-1/2} \|f\|_{\ell^1}
$$

hold for the operator $T_K$ as described above?

I expect that one can choose the constant $C$ to depend only on the support condition assumed on $K$.  Using the Fourier transform one can prove this bound when $K$ is translation-invariant, meaning it has the form $K(x,y) = \varphi(x-y)$.  Aside from this case I do not know how to proceed (or if the bound I hope for is true!).